# How do I create an answer for an equation using randomly generated numbers and operator?

Tags: python, variables, math, random

I'm wondering how to plus, subtract and multiply a randomly generated number from other random number with a random operator.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
ops = ['+','-','*']
op = random.choice(ops)
variable1 = random.randrange(1,10)
variable2 = random.randrange(1,10)
if op == '+':
    answer = sum(var1+var2)
elif op == '-':
      answer = sum(var1-var2)
elif op == '*':
      answer = sum(var1*var2)
```

I usually get an error message:
answer = sum(var1-var2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Sorry if this is a simple answer, still fresh to the whole python coding! :)

Comment: whay you want to use `sum`?as the `sum` function accept an iterator and sum up its items (if the type was sum-able )!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` is [for summing up an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) - meaning a list or something behaving as a list.

Just use `answer = var1 + var2`.

There is also a fun module named `operators` that [allows you to supply an operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) that mirrors the built-in operators, which would allow you to generalize this even further.

Something like this would probably be more pythonic :

```
import operators
ops = [operators.iadd, operators.imul, operators.isub]
# pick your op = ..
# pick your vars = ..

answer = op(var1, var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum` requires iterable. Here, you already know the answer but trying to give it to `sum` so no need, just remove it.

```
ops = ['+','-','*']
op = random.choice(ops)
var1 = random.randrange(1,10)
var2 = random.randrange(1,10)
if op == '+':
    answer = var1+var2
elif op == '-':
    answer = var1-var2
elif op == '*':
    answer = var1*var2
```